# element doesn't toggle off

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to accomplish is, when a user clicks on a +, the corresponding "answer" div appears on the right displaying information.
Right now it does open the correct "answer" div, but the div does not close if the same + is clicked again, which I would like for it close.
If the user clicks a different +, it will open that one just fine even if one was clicked before hand.

I've tried playing around with the code provided, but I'm not able to get the "answer" div to untoggle itself.

jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(e){
        var plus = $(this);
        if(plus.hasClass('expanded')){
            $('.content_box_display').empty();
            plus.removeClass('expanded');
        }else{
            var targetId = plus.attr('class').split('question')[1];
            $('.content_box_display').html($('#answer'+targetId).html());
            plus.addClass(' expanded');
        }
    });
});
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="et_pb_section  et_pb_section_2 et_section_regular">



                    <div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_1">


                <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4  et_pb_column_2">

                <div class="et_pb_text et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_text_align_center  et_pb_text_2">

<h1>Where Do You Have Pain?</h1>

            </div> <!-- .et_pb_text -->
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_row --><div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_2 et_pb_row_fullwidth et_pb_row_4col">


                <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4  et_pb_column_3 et_pb_column_empty">


            </div> <!-- .et_pb_column --><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4  et_pb_column_4">

                <div id="foot-diagram" class="et_pb_text et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_text_align_left  et_pb_text_3">

<div class="one_third et_column_last">
                    <div class="content_box">
<div id="toes" class="toggle question1"><a name="#answer1"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="content_box">
<div id="arch-heel" class="toggle question2"><a name="#answer2"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="content_box">
<div id="ankle" class="toggle question3"><a name="#answer3"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="content_box">
<div id="skin" class="toggle question4"><a name="#answer4"></a></div>
</div>
                </div><div class="clear"></div>

            </div> <!-- .et_pb_text -->
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_column --><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4  et_pb_column_5">

                <div class="et_pb_text et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_dark et_pb_text_align_left  et_pb_text_4">

<h3 style="float: left;">Click each</h3>
<div class="plus-sign" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; float: left; width: 20px; position: absolute; height: 20px; top: 20px; margin-left: 10px;"></div>
<p style="clear: both;">to view what type of pain is associated with that part of the foot</p>

            </div> <!-- .et_pb_text --><div id="yoga-answer" class="et_pb_text et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_dark et_pb_text_align_left  et_pb_text_5">

<div id="answer1">
<div class="blue-back animated">
<h2>Toes</h2>
<ul>
<li>Fungus Nail</li>
<li>Ingrown Toenail</li>
<li>Hammer Toe</li>
<li>Bunion</li>
<li>Bone Spur</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="answer2">
<div class="blue-back animated">
<h2>Arch &amp; Heel</h2>
<ul>
<li>Plantar Fasciitis</li>
<li>Heel Spur</li>
<li>Achilles Pain</li>
<li>Pump Bump</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="answer3">
<div class="blue-back animated">
<h2>Ankle</h2>
<ul>
<li>Fracture</li>
<li>Sprain</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="answer4">
<div class="blue-back animated">
<h2>Skin</h2>
<ul>
<li>Athlete’s Foot</li>
<li>Sprain</li>
<li>Other</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="question" class="content_box_display"></div>

            </div> <!-- .et_pb_text -->
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_column --><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4  et_pb_column_6 et_pb_column_empty">


            </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_row --><div id="blue-accords" class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_3">


                <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4  et_pb_column_7">

                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_accordion  et_pb_accordion_0">

            </div> <!-- .et_pb_accordion -->
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_row -->

            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#foot-diagram {
  height: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
#foot-diagram p {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #ddd;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  width: 85%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight:bold;
}


#foot-diagram a {
  font-size: 1.7em;

}
.plus-sign {
  display:inline-block;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background:url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/plus.png");
  background-size: contain;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.toggle {
  display:inline-block;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background:url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/plus.png");
  background-size: contain;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.toggle.expanded{
  background:url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/plus.png");
  background-size: contain;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}


.animated {
  animation: .55s fadeIn 0.25s ease-in-out both;
}

.content_box_display {
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.blue-back h2 {
  color: #005699 !important;
  padding-top: 18px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
.blue-back {
  padding: 0px 25px 25px 30px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.blue-back li a {
  color: #555 !important;
}
.blue-back p {
  line-height: 1.8em;
}
#answer1, #answer2, #answer3, #answer4, #answer5, #answer6, #answer7, #answer8, #answer9 {
  display: none;
}


#toes.toggle {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 240px;
  left: 285px;
}
#arch-heel.toggle {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 240px;
  left: 105px;
}
#ankle.toggle {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 40px;
  left: 70px;
}
#skin.toggle {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 170px;
  left: 145px;
}
```

Comment: I can't see the section you're referring to (the +) on the website: http://foothealth.wpengine.com/

Comment: *"Please view the site"* ... No. Provide relevant html structure here. Questions should be self contained as per [mcve]. We shouldn't have to go off site and try to poke through a whole site to review your issue

Comment: I apologize for not posting the HTML/CSS of the site, I was just about off work when I posted this question, but I have updated the question to have it.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your `slideToggle` does nothing because you already interting the content when clicked in questions.

Remove all and try that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(e){
        var plus = $(this);
        if(plus.hasClass('expanded')){
            $('.content_box_display').empty();
            plus.removeClass('expanded');
        }else{
            var targetId = plus.attr('class').split('question')[1];
            $('.content_box_display').html($('#answer'+targetId).html());
            plus.addClass(' expanded');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you input -- I've updated the javascript, and that WAS working great, until I added more animation, now I'm noticing that the toggle doesn't exactly 'shut off' when a new one is clicked. how can I get it to basically reset when another toggle is clicked? I've updated the code above in my question, and you can view it live at foothealth.wpengine.com

Comment: Yes its not shutting of because right now we are just removing the content of it. Looks like you have many unnecessary code for sliding. Just look at https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ and put/remove content before toggling it.

Comment: What do you mean I have unnecessary code for sliding, the code is exactly what you provided? Not only that but the code nolonger has .slideToggle() ?

Comment: By the way the toggle is working on bigger screens. But small screens the box is not "closing", the reason is that you are using `display:flex` on columns that forces the column on right (gives information) to be same height with column on left (foot picture).